# Force Maven Lifecycle for Project Module

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am using `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.4` to create a single JAR file that contains all of my (multi-module) project's core dependencies. From there, I make this module a dependency for all my other modules.  This allows me to have one place for all of the core dependencies to be defined and only one shade plugin relocation configuration, instead of having to copy & paste the same shade plugin information into each module that all want to shade dependencies in the same way.

However, the problem is that the shade-plugin does not run before the package phase.  So, if I run just `mvn test` the project fails to compile because these core dependencies are not gathered, shaded, relocated, until the `package` phase.

Is there a way that I can define in the POM a way that will always run this one module to the package phase regardless of the `mvn` phase specified at the top-level directory?

FYI: Guava 27.0-jre

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.my.app</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>app-thirdparty</artifactId>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <relocations>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>com.google</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>org.my.app.thirdparty.com.google</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>org.checkerframework</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>org.my.app.thirdparty.org.checkerframework</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>org.codehaus</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>org.my.app.thirdparty.org.codehaus</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
              </relocations>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Using a shaded jar as a dependency is usually a bad idea cause you loose all options to exclude dependencies via excludes mechanism im Maven.

Comment: Fair point.  However, since it is my own internal project JAR, and I get to control what exists in it, I don't want to exclude anything.

Comment: Yes true, but you give simply the dependency of that project/module and you have what you need. There is no need to create a shaded jar for that. The dependencies you have defined in your pom will also be available in your project which use this module. The classpath is automatically handled by Maven and you would go with the convention instead of trying to circumvent things which are not really a problem... in the end a shaded jar will always produce pain... The only good use case is to create executable jars...but not for dependencies...